# dragula loaded but not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, dragula

I am developing an Alfresco surf page that uses dragula. As alfresco 5 uses dojo ,  i use dojo to load dragula library.

```
 require(["${page.url.context}/res/components/js/dragula.js"], function(){
     dragula([document.getElementById('left-defaults')]);
 });
```

The library gets loaded ok but dragula is not being definded properly. If i try to use it, i get a  not defined error in browser like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dragula is not defined
at extractar:388
at runFactory (dojo.js:1147)
at execModule (dojo.js:1275)
at dojo.js:1310
at guardCheckComplete (dojo.js:1290)
at checkComplete (dojo.js:1305)
at onLoadCallback (dojo.js:1471)
at HTMLScriptElement.onLoad (dojo.js:1720).
```

Some pics of my problem.

[dragula library loaded ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2GIX.png)

[dragula browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rokgg.png)

why is this happening? Do i have to use another way to load and use dragula?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing formal parameter passed to callback function i.e.

```
require(["path/to/dragula.js"], function(dragula /*this is missing*/) {
    // you can use dragula param here
    ...
});
```

Look at the [dojo.require](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/require.html) to observe that if you want refer to module loaded at N-th index in array passed as first param to `require()` you need to provide formal parameters matching first N modules in array.

Comment: glad to hear, would you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote my answer?